# Trying to connect using Remmina 1.4.35

Tags: plugins, remmina

I am trying to connect a laptop and a single board PC. Both are at the same UBUNTU 23.10 release and both are at the same Remmina release 1.4.35. When I connect from the PC to the laptop it works fine. When I try to connect from the laptop to the PC I get Login Failed. The only difference I see is the PC has PLUGINS that the laptop doesn't those being EXEC and GVNC.

Using the laptop when it initially connects I see a windows style 'window' When I connect from the PC to the laptop I get a LINUX looking window. I believe that the PLUGIN GVNC is the issue. I have searched high and low for the GVNC plugin to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, yes, I have checked the passwords many many times....:)